# Can we exclude indexes to check in the /healthz/ready probe used in Sitecore Docker containers or Sitecore Managed Cloud?

Tags: solr, docker

In Sitecore Docker implementations and Sitecore Managed Cloud implementations, containers have a liveness probe that determines whether the Sitecore instance is ready and alive. In cases where it fails, it brings down the container and attempts to restart it.

One of these health checks is a Solr Dependency check.  This check takes the list of indexes that are configured in Sitecore and attempts to find them in the local environment.

In most cases, this is sufficient.  But there are index customizations available today that allow an index to be sourced from a different Solr environment, and not need to be created in the Solr environment that is listed in ConnectionStrings.config.  (Think SaaS based Solr Cores).

In these cases, is there a way to exclude (or include) specific indexes in which the liveness probe should check (or ignore)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the existing configurator that registers the health check for Solr. This can be found in the patch *Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config*.

```
<configurator type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.DependencyInjection.ContentSearchServicesConfigurator, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
```

Internally there is a function for loading the list of Solr core names from configuration.

```
var path = "sitecore/contentSearch/configuration/indexes/index/param[@desc='core']"
XmlNodeList xmlNodeLists = ConfigReader.GetConfiguration().SelectNodes(path);
```

One solution would be to patch in a list of cores to ignore and then override this code to handle the rest.